# How to change the way Ruby on Rails parses two digit year input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, activerecord

I have a form that accepts a date from a text field in the format (m/d/yy).

When the date gets saved (using ActiveRecord), it gets parsed as the year "0014" instead of "2014." In this field's case, I'd like it to always guess the century as 2000.

Here's a [failing] test in the console:

```
2.0.0-p247 :021 > g.update_attributes(:date_completed => "3/4/14")
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.7ms)  UPDATE `goals` SET `date_completed` = '0014-03-04', `updated_at` = '2014-06-30 21:36:06' WHERE `goal_tracker_goals`.`id` = 10
   (1.7ms)  COMMIT
 => true 
2.0.0-p247 :023 > g.date_completed
 => Sun, 04 Mar 0014
```

I assume there's an ActiveRecord method to overwrite somewhere or a configuration value to set.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there something wrong with parsing the date string yourself? No one is forcing you to blindly dump things from `params` straight into your models, your controllers are allowed to handle data format conversions (I'd even go so far as to say that this **is** the controller's job, Rails does it wrong by trying to push all that logic into the models).

Comment: Only in the interest of keeping it DRY. There are many date inputs throughout the site and m/d/yy is the preferred format. I was just wondering if there was a method to overwrite or config value that would tell Rails to interpret two digit year as this century. Kind of a long shot, I know.

Comment: If the values are named consistently then you could hack a before filter into `ApplicationController`, if they're not then you could add your own macro to pre-process things on a per-controller basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bold solution, but it's the only one that covers all cases. Anywhere in the app, when an attribute of type date is set, it will send it through `Date.parse()` before it writes.

```
# initializers/active_record_extension_parse_date_writer.rb

module ActiveRecordExtensionParseDateWriter

  private

  def write_attribute(attr_name, value)
    if self.class.column_types.fetch(attr_name.to_s).type == :date
      d = (Date.parse(value.to_s)) rescue nil
      super(attr_name, d)
    else
      super
    end
  end

end

# include the extension
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ActiveRecordExtensionParseDateWriter)
```

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
g.date_completed=Date.parse("3/4/14")
```

To bypass default locale, try: [ *after having updated the question this is the right answer* ]

```
g.date_completed=Date.strptime("3/4/14","%m/%d/%y") # %m: month, %d: day, %y: 2-digit year
```

Comment: Thanks. This works in the console, but I'm more concerned about the case of accepting a form submission where the date field comes from a text input in the format of (m/d/yy). I've updated the question.

Comment: Then you can try my second suggestion, it's ready for that scenario. Just change "3/4/14" with the incoming variable. In the 2nd suggestion, the string is parsed as m/d/y (year with 2 digits)